# bash - execute curl and export base64 file to variable

Tags: bash, curl, base64

I'm developing a script that downloads a file, convert it to base64 and export the code to variable. At the moment i can only accomplish this in 2 steps (which force me to save the file). How can I directly download and export the content without saving the fine... i.e. in one line?

This is what i'm doing...

```
#!/bin/bash  -x 

curl -o top10.jpg "http://www.somesite.com/top10.jpg"
top10=$( base64 top10.jpg)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution):

```
top10=$(base64 <(curl "http://www.somesite.com/top10.jpg"))
```

Or, as Etan Reisner points out in a comment, a pipeline will work as well:

```
top10=$(curl "http://www.somesite.com/top10.jpg" | base64)
```

While a process substitution results in a *filename* getting passed to `base64` (either the name of a FIFO or a named file descriptor such as `/dev/fd/63`, depending on platform), the pipeline passes its data to `base64` via *stdin* - the net effect is the same here.

The advantage of using a pipeline is that is POSIX-compliant, whereas process substitution is a `bash`-specific feature.